# Python: Changing visual parameters of ptitprince repo derived from seaborn and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, seaborn, graph-visualization

I am using a github repository called ptitprince, which is derived from seaborn and matplotlib, to generate graphs.

For example, this is the code using the ptitprince repo:

```
# coding: utf8

import pandas as pd
import ptitprince as pt
import seaborn as sns
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#sns.set(style="darkgrid")
#sns.set(style="whitegrid")
#sns.set_style("white")
sns.set(style="whitegrid",font_scale=2)
import matplotlib.collections as clt

df = pd.read_csv ("u118phag.csv", sep= ",")
df.head()

savefigs = True
figs_dir = 'figs'

if savefigs:
    # Make the figures folder if it doesn't yet exist
    if not os.path.isdir('figs'):
        os.makedirs('figs')

#automation
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 5))
#f.subplots_adjust(hspace=0,wspace=0)
dx = "Treatment"; dy = "score"; ort = "v"; pal = "Set2"; sigma = .2
ax=pt.RainCloud(x = dx, y = dy, data = df, palette = pal, bw = sigma,
                 width_viol = .6, ax = ax, move=.2, offset=.1, orient = ort, pointplot = True)
f.show()

if savefigs:
    f.savefig('figs/figure20.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=500)
```

[which generates the following graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZTYK.png)

The raw code not using ptitprince is as follows and produces the same graph as above:

```
# coding: utf8

import pandas as pd
import ptitprince as pt
import seaborn as sns
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#sns.set(style="darkgrid")
#sns.set(style="whitegrid")
#sns.set_style("white")
sns.set(style="whitegrid",font_scale=2)
import matplotlib.collections as clt

df = pd.read_csv ("u118phag.csv", sep= ",")
df.head()

savefigs = True
figs_dir = 'figs'

if savefigs:
    # Make the figures folder if it doesn't yet exist
    if not os.path.isdir('figs'):
        os.makedirs('figs')

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 5))
dy="Treatment"; dx="score"; ort="h"; pal = sns.color_palette(n_colors=1)

#adding color
pal = "Set2"
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 5))
ax=pt.half_violinplot( x = dx, y = dy, data = df, palette = pal, bw = .2, cut = 0.,
                      scale = "area", width = .6, inner = None, orient = ort)
ax=sns.stripplot( x = dx, y = dy, data = df, palette = pal, edgecolor = "white",
                 size = 3, jitter = 1, zorder = 0, orient = ort)
ax=sns.boxplot( x = dx, y = dy, data = df, color = "black", width = .15, zorder = 10,\
            showcaps = True, boxprops = {'facecolor':'none', "zorder":10},\
            showfliers=True, whiskerprops = {'linewidth':2, "zorder":10},\
               saturation = 1, orient = ort)


if savefigs:
    f.savefig('figs/figure21.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=500)
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is to figure out how to modify the graph so that I can (1) move the plots closer together, so there is not so much white space between them, and (2) shift the x-axis to the right, so that I can make the distribution (violin) plot wider without it getting cut in half by the y-axis.

I have tried to play around with `subplots_adjust()` as you can see in the first box of code, but I receive an error. I cannot figure out how to appropriately use this function, or even if that will actually bring the different graphs closer together.

I also know that I can increase the distribution size by increasing this value `width = .6`, but if I increase it too high, the distribution plot begins to being cut off by the y-axis. I can't figure out if I need to adjust the overall plot using the `plt.subplots`,or if I need to move each individual plot.

Any advice or recommendations on how to change the visuals of the graph? I've been staring at this for awhile, and I can't figure out how to make seaborn/matplotlib play nicely with ptitprince.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to change the interval of X-axis being shown using `ax.set_xbound` (put a lower value than you currently have for the beginning).

Comment: Your answer is read by others aside from the OP. You need to present it in a manner that is understood by everyone without having them pull their hairs trying to figure out which line number you are pointing to.